# How To Apply jquery filtering on click of html link

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, replace, filtering

I have applied jQuery filters on a table with few hundreds rows and it works fine.

But I want to make few HTML links on top of table so users can click on that link to apply filter (instead of typing) for instance. List all record with city name Washington, something like that:

Desired Filtering

```
<a href="">List all records with city name Washington</a>
```

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Desired Filtering</h2>

<h3><a href="">List all records with city name Washington</a></h3>

<hr />

<h2>Working Filterable Table</h2>
<p>Type something in the input field to search the table for first names, last names or emails:</p>
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<br><br>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>City</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
      <td>New York</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@mail.com</td>
      <td>Washington</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      <td>New York</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Anja</td>
      <td>Ravendale</td>
      <td>a_r@test.com</td>
      <td>New York</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mathew</td>
      <td>Stars</td>
      <td>a_z@test.com</td>
      <td>Washintgon</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

> so users can click on that link to apply filter (instead of typing)

You can store the filter that you want in the link using a `data-` attribute, then apply that to the search input using `.val()`.

```
<a href="#" class='addfilter' data-filter="washington">List all records with city name Washington</a>
```

```
$(".addfilter").click(function() {
  var filter = $(this).data("filter");
  $("#myInput").val(filter);
  $("#myInput").trigger("keyup");
  return false;
});
```

Here I've given the link a class `addfilter` so that you can add new links without needing to change the code.  The `.click` handler has `return false;` (or could use `.preventDefault` to stop the `<a>` from navigating away (the `href='#'` also stops the `<a>` from changing the whole page).

Updated snippet:

```js
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });
});

$(".addfilter").click(function() {
  var filter = $(this).data("filter");
  $("#myInput").val(filter);
  $("#myInput").trigger("keyup");
  return false;
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Desired Filtering</h2>

<h3>
  <a href="#" class='addfilter' data-filter="washington">List all records with city name Washington</a>
  <br/>
  <a href="#" class='addfilter' data-filter="new york">List all records with city name New York</a></h3>

<hr />

<h2>Working Filterable Table</h2>
<p>Type something in the input field to search the table for first names, last names or emails:</p>
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<br><br>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>City</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
      <td>New York</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@mail.com</td>
      <td>Washington</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      <td>New York</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Anja</td>
      <td>Ravendale</td>
      <td>a_r@test.com</td>
      <td>New York</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mathew</td>
      <td>Stars</td>
      <td>a_z@test.com</td>
      <td>Washintgon</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

For the above, in order to "apply" the filter, I've used `.trigger("keyup")` which calls your existing code.  This is to keep the number of changes to a minimum; in practice you would want to pull this out into its own function.  You also might like to use `input` instead of `keyup` as it will catch mouse-paste etc, giving something like:

```
function applyFilter(value) {
    value = value.toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
}
$(".addfilter").click(function() {
    var filter = $(this).data("filter");
    $("#myInput").val(filter);
    applyFilter(filter);
    return false;
});
$("#myInput").on("input", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    applyFilter(value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... it is exactly I was looking. 

Please guide further, is it possible to link to these "html links on this page"  from another page, say... this code snippet is working on page-1.html

can I make a link on page-2.html something like...

<a href=page-1.html?washington>See All Washington listing here</a>

Comment: Sure, in the doc.ready check the window.location.search - there are detailed methods to extract an exact parameter in other answers on SO - then put that in #myInput and apply the filter.